# how to edit many lines in VI

Tags: vi

I got a file with 1000 lines and I need to replace let's say first 500 lines with any another number - for example 0, and next 500 lines with number that is in this line + 1

Comment: Why vi specifically? There are better tools for this task.

Comment: I will be working with vi for some time and would like to learn more about it. I could just write a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first of the lines you want to replace, you can do:

```
500dd
```

And then:

```
500I
```

Input the text you want to place in the 500 lines, follow with enter and exit edit mode. Voila!

If you want to increment numbers written in multiple lines, you could use a macro.

Try:

```
qq<C-A>jq499@q
```

- the first q begins the recording of a macro
- the second q is where the macro is to be stored
- C-A means "increase the number in the current line"
- j - go to next line
- third q - finish recording the macro
- 499 - repeat 499 times
- @q - repeat the macro stored in q

Answer (score 0):

For selecting a range use `begin,end/pattern/s//pattern`/.

Example:

```
1,500s/aaa/bbb/|501,1000s/aaa/ccc/
```

Would replace `aaa` by `bbb` in lines from `1` until `500` and `aaa` by `ccc` from `501` until `1000` (all in one single line)!!!

Comment: What is the pattern for anything? I thought it would be * but not

Comment: `.*` or you can use `^.*$` for anything from the beginning of line `^` until the end `$`

Answer (score 0):

You could record a macro by typing `qacc<whatever you want><ESC>jq` and then run that by typing `500@a`.